$24$ meteorites reach the Earth's surface each year. Prob. that no more than $3$ such meteorites will come in one month. Solution verification.
An average of $24$ meteorites of a fixed size reach the Earth's surface each year. Determine the approximate probability that no more than 3 such meteorites will arrive in September 2028.

Given that an average of $24$ meteors hit the Earth per year, we can find the monthly average by dividing by $12$: $\lambda = \frac{24}{12} = 2 \ (\text{meteors per month})$
The Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda = 2$ describes the probability of $k$ events (meteors) occurring in a fixed interval (one month):
$$P(X=k)= \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$
We need to calculate: $\mathbb{P}(X \leq 3) = \mathbb{P}(X=0) + \mathbb{P}(X=1) + \mathbb{P}(X=2) + \mathbb{P}(X=3)$ where:

$\mathbb{P}(X=0) = e^{-2}$
$\mathbb{P}(X=1) = 2e^{-2}$
$\mathbb{P}(X=2) = 2e^{-2}$
$\mathbb{P}(X=3) = \frac{4e^{-2}}{3}$

Therefore, the probability is equal to:
$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq 3) = 1 - e^{-2} - 2e^{-2} - 2e^{-2} - \frac{4e^{-2}}{3} = \frac{19}{3} e^{-2}$$
Is that correct?

Seems to me that one is assuming some sort of independence in the timing of meteorite events, which may not be consistent with the actual facts. Meteorites may be correlated with meteor showers, which occur at specific times of the year every year, which would increase the probability of more than three in a month.

Assuming that $24$ meteorites on average hit eart per year, it's correct. If we knew it is exactly, then one would need to use Binomial distribution, well approximated by Poisson, though. Of course, we assume independence in both cases.

You are given a specific month (having $30$ days) in a specific year (having $366$ days), so - again assuming a uniform distribution over time - you could improve your monthly average slightly to be $\lambda = 24\cdot \frac {30}{366} = \frac{120}{61}$. Other than that, you are correct - and given the "approximate probability" requirement, I doubt the "improvement" is expected, either. There are far more than $24$ meteor shower meteors each year, so those would be outside the "fixed size" of this statistic. Though such would be beyond the scope of a math exercise anyway.
